# C# Pick random line from an embedded text file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do you pick a random line from an embedded text file?

When I run the program it crashes and gives me this error (Illegal characters in path) On this line ( String[] randFirst = File.ReadAllLines(Separis_Fantasy_Tools_PE.Properties.Resources.fnames); )

This is what I have.

```
private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String nFirstName;
        String nLastName;

        Random fname = new Random();
        Random lname = new Random();


            String[] randFirst = File.ReadAllLines(Separis_Fantasy_Tools_PE.Properties.Resources.fnames);
            nFirstName = randFirst[fname.Next(randFirst.Length)];

            String[] randLast = File.ReadAllLines(Separis_Fantasy_Tools_PE.Properties.Resources.lnames);
            nLastName = randLast[lname.Next(randLast.Length)];


        txtCharacterName.Text = nFirstName + " " + nLastName;
        return;


    }
```

Comment: What is not working about it? Is it throwing an error? Is it giving bad output?

Comment: When I run the program it crashes and gives me this error (Illegal characters in path) On this line ( String[] randFirst = File.ReadAllLines(Separis_Fantasy_Tools_PE.Properties.Resources.fnames); )

Comment: That might be something you would want to add to your question.... Big difference between it not outputting right and exploding..

Comment: You can use one Random generator, too. Maybe give us some information about the Path used to load the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Separis_Fantasy_Tools_PE.Properties.Resources.fnames` is the text file itself, not a path to the text file.

```
private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String nFirstName;
    String nLastName;

    Random rnd= new Random();


    String[] randFirst = Separis_Fantasy_Tools_PE.Properties.Resources.fnames.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    nFirstName = randFirst[rnd.Next(randFirst.Length)];

    String[] randLast = Separis_Fantasy_Tools_PE.Properties.Resources.lnames.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    nLastName = randLast[rnd.Next(randLast.Length)];


    txtCharacterName.Text = nFirstName + " " + nLastName;
    return;


}
```

One other change, you don't need two random objects, just use one and call `next` twice. You likely don't need worry about it but you should also be aware that the way you wrote your code you could potentially get the [same random number every time you call your function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number) (if you do it really fast).

Comment: This has helped me out tremendously. Great answer.